# ExpressionEngine 3 Single Entry

Tags: add-on, ee3, addons

I know with EE2 there was a great addon by [@Viget Labs](https://devot-ee.com/developers/viget-labs) called [Single Entry](https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/single-entry) that limited entries in channels to a single use. Is there nothing for EE3 that can accomplish this easily? It's amazing to me that this hasn't been absorbed by Ellis Lab yet as a core feature in the channel settings.

Answer (score 0):

I've never had cause to limit a channel by single entry. Instead for those sort of page/content types I tend to use Low Variables where you set up a Group, and add some custom fields to suit the content.

Comment: So you don't use a channel for the home page, about us page, etc...  ?

Comment: Not on every site no, it varies according to the needs of the content, the client and the site structure.

Comment: I guess I'm not following the non-usage. Would need to wrap my head around it. How would your clients manage the content within those entries without access to the Channel Entry Template?

Comment: Clients have access to Low Variables "variables" which they can update as necessary. That's what Low Variables does, let clients manage items of content that don't always fit into standard entries (and a whole lot more besides).

Comment: I guess I'll need to look into it more then...